# Using Node and mysql. Insert fails at string variable

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, sql-insert

I am trying to insert a string variable into my database and the boolean and int go in just fine, but it always tells me

> error: column "spike" does not exist

(spike is what is in the string variable)

```
let sql2 = "INSERT INTO words (gameNumber, wordsOrdered, guessed, unkey) VALUES (2, "+wordsV[1]+", "+guessed[1]+", "+key[1]+" )"
pool.query(sql2, function(err, result){
```

The wordsV is an array of strings the guessed is a bool and goes in, and the key is an int and goes in.

Answer (score 0):

you need escape values

```js
let sql2 = "INSERT INTO words (gameNumber, wordsOrdered, guessed, unkey) VALUES (2, '"+wordsV[1]+"', '"+guessed[1]+"', '"+key[1]+"' )"
pool.query(sql2, function(err, result){
```

but the best way is to escape the values correctly: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape your sql values like this (https://www.databasestar.com/sql-escape-single-quote/):

```
let sql2 = "INSERT INTO words (gameNumber, wordsOrdered, guessed, unkey) VALUES (2, '"+wordsV[1]+"', '"+guessed[1]+"', '"+key[1]+"' )"
```